# Getting stuck in a while loop - values updating, but while loop is stuck

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

I have set up an input for a file name at the top of my script.
After it is entered I am checking if it is correct before running the rest of the script.

I have tried an if statement instead of the while loop, however this runs once and then skips to the print line underneath, however the while loop even when the value it is checking for prints as True, still keeps returning to the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am complete newb to this, so any help is much appreciated.

Simon

```
def checkinput():
    maybefileloc = input("Enter Full file location and name : ")
    print("confirming file as : ", maybefileloc)
    fcn = "Y" == input("Is this correct? - Yes or No : ")
    print(maybefileloc, fcn)
    return (maybefileloc, fcn)


maybefile, fileconf = checkinput()


while fileconf == False:
    checkinput()


fileloc = maybefile

print('Running conversion on '+fileloc+', please wait for line length checking')
```

This is my IDLE output for a test run:

Enter Full file location and name : E:/asdljhjklh

confirming file as :  E:/asdljhjklh

Is this correct? - Yes or No : n

E:/asdljhjklh False

Enter Full file location and name : E:/asdjljhjjjjj

confirming file as :  E:/asdjljhjjjjj

Is this correct? - Yes or No : Y

E:/asdjljhjjjjj True

Enter Full file location and name :

*** It seems to be getting stuck even through true is being passed??

Answer (score 0):

1. You assigned the name 'fileconf' to equal check_input(). This means that when you start the loop:

```py
while fileconfig == False:
   check_input()
```

what is happening is you are calling the function each time you want to check if it is false and then running it again after that:

```py
while check_input() == False:
    check_input()
```

After the while statement is executed it will infinitely run the function meaning it gets stuck in the loop.

To fix this you could embed the 'while' loop into the function and save a few lines of code:

```py
def checkinput():
    while True:
        maybefileloc = input("Enter Full file location and name : ")
        print("confirming file as : ", maybefileloc)
        fcn = "Y" == input("Is this correct? - Yes or No : ").upper()
        print(maybefileloc, fcn)
        if fcn is True:
            return str(maybefileloc)

print(f'Running conversion on "{checkinput()}", please wait for line length checking')
```

There is no need for a 'break' statement in the loop as the 'return' statement already terminates the function and thus the loop.